# Show that the number of ordered basis of a vector space of dimension n over a field of order p is multiple of n!

Tags: linear-algebra, elementary-number-theory

> Let $n$ be a positive integer and $p$ a prime. Show that the number of
> ordered basis of a vector space of dimension $n$ over a field of order $p$ is
> $(p^n − 1)(p^n − p)(p^n − p^2)\cdot...\cdot(p^n − p^{n−1})$.
> Deduce that this number is a multiple of $n!$.

Here is an argument

Let $V$ be a vector space of dimension $n$ over a field of order $p$, and let ${v_1, v_2, ..., v_n}$ be a basis of $V$. Any ordered basis of $V$ can be obtained by permuting the basis vectors ${v_1, v_2, ..., v_n}$.

Consider the first position in the ordered basis. There are $p^{n-1}$ choices for which nonzero scalar multiple of $v_1$ to put in that position (since $v_1$ and the zero vector are the only vectors in the span of $v_1$). Once we have chosen the first basis vector, there are $p^n-p$ choices for the second position (since we cannot choose a scalar multiple of $v_1$, and every other vector in the span of $v_1$ is a scalar multiple of $v_2$), then $p^n-p^2$ choices for the third position (since we cannot choose a scalar multiple of $v_1$ or $v_2$, and every other vector in the span of $v_1$ and $v_2$ is a scalar multiple of $v_3$), and so on. Therefore, the total number of ordered bases is:

$$(p^n-1)\cdot(p^n-p)\cdot(p^n-p^2)\cdot...\cdot(p^n-p^{n-1})$$

This is the desired formula.

To see that this number is a multiple of $n!$, note that the formula above counts each ordered basis $n!$ times, since the order of the basis vectors matters. Therefore, the actual number of ordered bases is:

$$\frac{(p^n-1)\cdot(p^n-p)\cdot(p^n-p^2)\cdot...\cdot(p^n-p^{n-1})}{n!}$$

which is an integer since $n!$ divides the product of any $n$ consecutive integers.

Please cheak or give another solution

Comment: the second sentence is wrong because there are bases which are not rearrangements of your given basis (if it was true, why would you need the rest of the argument? the answer would just be n!). The next part is also wrong e.g. (a) there are only $p-1$ nonzero scalar multiples of $v_1$, not $p^{n-1}$ (b) there's no reason that the first element of an arbitrary basis must be a scalar multiple of $v_1$.  Also none of the vectors in the span of $v_1$, except the zero vector, are scalar multiples of $v_2$.

Answer (score 1):

Each unordered base consists of $n$ distinct vectors and can therefore be ordered in $n!$ ways. So the number of ordered bases equals the product of $n!$ and the number of unordered bases.